# git bisect in combination with CRLF/LF

Tags: git, newline, gitattributes, core.autocrlf, git-bisect

I am trying to `git bisect` some bad behavior in a public repo.

The repo has:

- some commits with CRLF (I am on MacOS, so expecting LF)
- a `.gitattributes` [file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/contiki-os/contiki/master/.gitattributes) in its root, normalizing .c, .h, and .java files

As I understand it, none of the present `.git/config` or `~/.gitconfig` should matter, as `.gitattributes` has precedence.

My problem relates to this: when I do a checkout of a commit with CRLF, the local files are modified with LF. These files show up as modified upon `git status`. Then if I try to check out another commit, git refuses in order to protect my local changes. Fine.

In the `checkout` case, I can force it with `-f`, and go on.

The problem is that I cannot seem to force `git bisect skip`. If I try, `git` tells me to stash changes. I cannot get clean working files (stashing leaves me with modified newlines anyway), and I cannot skip.

I've tried copying over a temporary `.gitattributes` in order to make `bisect` leave the newlines unchanged, but then it complains about the changes in `.gitattributes` being unsaved.

Is there a way to force `bisect`?

Comment: Ugh. I'd try the temporary `.gitattributes` file plus setting `git update-index --skip-worktree` on it, and hope there are no changes to `.gitattributes` in any of the bisect-range commits. Failing that, keep a temporary `.gitattributes` you can swap in and out, swap it out to go to the next bisect, swap it back in and `git checkout -f` to update, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> none of the present .git/config or ~/.gitconfig should matter, as .gitattributes has precedence

not really, the local file for gitattributes is `.git/info/attributes`, and it has precedence over whatever `.gitattributes` file in repository